# How do I map custom error keys in Restkit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit, restkit-0.20

When a user signs up successfully on our server, it responds with a 200 status code and a JSON payload like this:

```
{
    "error": null,
    "result": {
        "auth": {
            "created_utc": 1420740197,
            "device_token": "rQZJddrbD5tyEpznb8bVKeGlHqRNGyvOgDR;tQJBkpkfAXO6DQ4lNiG17lzu6IDc0hVBfR3RrN9o0txRQIYAa6fnf5d9LNaSRDMk9LrplgkITuMC37v;;;rvG35CJvV7dWZ5TQVYUWeHwAABvKvzTRpSDw5Qg9jQrmiUHLZptegFY=76421420740197"
        },
        "display_name": "a",
        "email": "a@a.com",
        "user_id": 7642,
        "username": "a"
    }
}
```

But if a@a.com tries to sign up again, it responds with a 400 status code and a JSON payload like this:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 805,
        "message": "there is another user with that username"
    },
    "result": null
}
```

I tried mapping the error, so that when Restkit returns an error, I get the message as well as the code. These are the ways I tried to do that:

```
RKObjectMapping *errorMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[RKErrorMessage class]];
[errorMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKAttributeMapping attributeMappingFromKeyPath:@"error.message" toKeyPath:@"errorMessage"]];

RKResponseDescriptor *errorDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:errorMapping method:RKRequestMethodAny pathPattern:nil keyPath:nil statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassClientError)];

[self.objectManager addResponseDescriptor:errorDescriptor];
```

This one obviously only gets the message part of the error to return with this output:

```
Error Domain=org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain Code=1004 "there is another user with that username" UserInfo=0x7feefcf8a730 {RKObjectMapperErrorObjectsKey=(
"there is another user with that username"
), NSLocalizedDescription=there is another user with that username}
```

So then I tried making a subclass of RKErrorMessage:

```
#import "RKErrorMessage.h"

@interface TAG_RKErrorMessage : RKErrorMessage

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *errorCode;

@end
```

And changed the mapping to this:

```
RKObjectMapping *errorMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[TAG_RKErrorMessage class]];
[errorMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKAttributeMapping attributeMappingFromKeyPath:@"error.message" toKeyPath:@"errorMessage"]];
[errorMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKAttributeMapping attributeMappingFromKeyPath:@"error.code" toKeyPath:@"errorCode"]];
```

and that resulted in the exact same output:

```
Error Domain=org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain Code=1004 "there is another user with that username" UserInfo=0x7fa16c627ce0 {RKObjectMapperErrorObjectsKey=(
"there is another user with that username"
), NSLocalizedDescription=there is another user with that username}
```

So lastly I tried this mapping to at least try to get the dictionary show up as the `RKObjectMapperErrorObjectsKey` of the `NSError`'s `userInfo`:

```
RKObjectMapping *errorMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[RKErrorMessage class]];
[errorMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKAttributeMapping attributeMappingFromKeyPath:@"error" toKeyPath:@"errorMessage"]];
```

And that resulted in this output:

```
Error Domain=org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain Code=1004 "<null>" UserInfo=0x7ff8abe678e0 {RKObjectMapperErrorObjectsKey=(
(null)
), NSLocalizedDescription=<null>}
```

Now I'm stuck at this point. How can I map the keys of my server's error response so that I can get access to the `code` that is returned as well as the `message` as two separate values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've likely mapped your TAG_RKErrorMessage instance correctly. Have you attempted to extract it from the NSError you've been given? You can use the RKObjectMapperErrorObjectsKey as a key on the NSError's userInfo dictionary to get an array of all mapped error messages:

```
NSArray* objectMapperErrorObjectsArray = [error.userInfo objectForKey:RKObjectMapperErrorObjectsKey];
```

You can then loop through that array to check each error for conditions you want to respond to, for example, if you wanted to respond to a 403 response code with the error message "Invalid token", you could do:

```
NSArray* objectMapperErrorObjectsArray = [error.userInfo objectForKey:RKObjectMapperErrorObjectsKey];
for (RKErrorMessage* objectMapperErrorObject in objectMapperErrorObjectsArray)
{
    if ([objectMapperErrorObject.errorMessage isEqual:@"Invalid token"])
    {
        if (operation.HTTPRequestOperation.response.statusCode == 403)
        {
            //Code to handle a 403 response status code when error message is "Invalid token".
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Gonna make one change and do `for (TAG_RKErrorMessage* objectMapperErrorObject in objectMapperErrorObjectsArray)` so I can get access to the errorCode. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

**Just a hint**: if you want to use the built-in `RKErrorMessage` without creating any subclass, you can map all error JSON attributes to `RKErrorMessage.userInfo` in this way:

**Objective-C**:

```
RKObjectMapping *errorMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[RKErrorMessage class]];
[errorMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKAttributeMapping attributeMappingFromKeyPath:nil toKeyPath:@"userInfo"]];

RKResponseDescriptor *errorDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:errorMapping method:RKRequestMethodAny pathPattern:nil keyPath:"error" statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassClientError)];
```

**Swift**:

```
let errorMapping = RKObjectMapping(forClass: RKErrorMessage.self);
errorMapping.addPropertyMapping(RKAttributeMapping(fromKeyPath: nil, toKeyPath: "userInfo"));

let errorResponseDescriptor = RKResponseDescriptor(
    mapping: errorMapping,
    method: RKRequestMethod.Any,
    pathPattern: nil,
    keyPath: "error", 
    statusCodes: RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(UInt(RKStatusCodeClassClientError)))
);
```